# UGREEN M2 SSD External Hard Drive Keeps Connecting and Disconnecting

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, usb, ssd, external-hard-drive

I'm facing one of the biggest problems in my life, I have UGREEN USB M2 External Hard Drive. It had no media for the first time but when I upload the framework 'Asmedia ASMT-2105 Firmware (ASM1051, ASM1053)' Instead of ASMT-2235, now it kept connecting and disconnecting all the time.
I've tried the higher performance and uncheck the checkbox in the USB driver in the power management.
I used MPTool for ASMT 2235, the problem was just "No Media" The USB was showing in the MPTool interface
like this :

**Image is just an example**

[image]

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.  Statements like "When I upload the framework" are not clear.  Additionally isn't this device an enclosure, why are you attempting to use it, without an actual supported disk?  You can [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: Does it do this on other PC's?

Comment: Which make and model M2 drive did you put in it?

Comment: @Moab Yup the same thing on other PC's

Comment: When you say it had no media at first, please explain what you mean.